# Regex to find words without double "L"

Tags: regex

Trying to fetch all words in a text that only contain one consecutive letter "l" case-insensitive.

For example:
"Hello, have you seen the large halo around the sun?"

- large -> captured
- halo -> captured

I tried so many combinations, but none even came close. I suppose I should use negative lookahead, negative lookbehind or the "\1" previous capturing group but I've never quite understood how to use these an generally avoided these and all my attempts at using these failed.

Comment: You should treat it as "match a word with `l` unless it contains `ll`" - > `\b(?!\w*?ll)\w*l\w*`

Comment: `\b\w*(?<!l)l(?!l)\w*` [will match](https://regex101.com/r/faK1yF/1) `illegal`. `\b(?!\w*?ll)\w*l\w*` [won't](https://regex101.com/r/faK1yF/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?i)\b(?!\w*?ll)\w*l\w*
/\b(?!\w*?ll)\w*l\w*/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/faK1yF/3)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\w*?ll)` - no `ll` allowed after any 0+ "word" chars: digits, letters, `_`s (as few as possible)
- `\w*l\w*` - 0+ word chars, `l` and again 0+ word chars.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for explanations! I always have a hard time with the "?!" and "!?" assertions, no matter how much I read about them

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression (with the case-indifferent flag set), which should work with most every regex engine.

```
\b[a-km-z]*l(?:[a-km-z]+l)*[a-km-z]*\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j86AV2/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
\b           # match a word break
[a-km-z]*    # match 0+ letters other than 'l'
l            # match 'l'
(?:          # begin non-capture group
  [a-km-z]+  # match 1+ letters other than 'l'
  l          # match 'l' 
)            # end non-capture group
*            # execute non-capture group 0+ times
[a-km-z]*    # match 0+ letters other than 'l'
\b           # match a word break
```

With PCRE (PHP) and some other regex engines you can use [subroutine calls](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to reduce repetition and the chances of errors. Here that would be

```
\b([a-km-z])*l(?:(?1)+l)*(?1)*\b
```

or

```
\b(?P<allbutl>[a-km-z])*l(?:(?P>allbutl)+l)*(?P>allbutl)*\b
```

The use of a subroutine with a named capture group, when the latter's content is complex, can also improve readability. I mention this as general information, and do not necessarily advocate the use of a subroutine here.

Comment: Nice answer (Not sure if it is intentional, but the character class will also match a comma) +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, you’ll have to admit it looks better with the commas. This is one of those “will never know why” episodes. I’ll fix it in the PDT morning. Thanks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland *you’ll have to admit it looks better with the commas* - No, it does not, because if something is wrong, it is not in any way "better" when it comes to code. Downvote is due until you fix this issue. One more thing: `_` is not allowed in named group names in some regex flavors, I would remove it from the example, too.

Comment: @Wiktor, my feeble attempt at self-deprecating humour seems to have missed its mark. Oh, well.